# Get approximately evenly spaced integers, in a certain range?

Tags: algorithm

I have an array of unknown length.

I want to find five index values that are approximately evenly distributed along the array, and always include the first and last values.

For example, if I have an array of length 20, I'd like the index values:

```
0, 4, 9, 14, 19
```

back.

Of course, if the array length doesn't divide neatly by 5, this gets more tricky.

Any clever ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: well one way is to divide the array length-1 by 5 and go from there. which is also why im voting to close this on the grounds that you're not giving an attempted solution, and that it's such a simple problem that you should have done so without much trouble, unless of course you dont understand maths at all, in which case the thread should also be closed, and so on, and so forth.

Comment: update: jsfiddle with a first attempt http://jsfiddle.net/4mqBd/

Comment: Just a guess, but arithmetic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/cwyzz/)***

If you have an array

```
var array = get();
```

Then just check the length and use those numbers

```
var first = 0;
var last = array.length;
var skip = parseInt(array.length / 4);
for( var i = first; i < last; i += skip ){
 //work with array[i]
 console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you:

```
function range(start, end){
  var ra = [];
  for(var i=0,s=start,l=end-s+1; i<l; i++,s++){
    ra[i] = s;
  }
  return ra;
}
function arrayEvery(yourArray, start, every){
  var newArray = [], yl = yourArray.length;
  var al = yl % every === 0 ? yl/every : Math.ceil((yl-start)/every);
  for(var i=start,n=0; n<al; i+=every,n++){
    newArray[n] = yourArray[i];
  }
  if(newArray[0] !== yourArray[0])newArray.unshift(yourArray[0]);
  if(newArray[newArray.length-1] === yourArray[yl-1]){
    return newArray;
  }
  else{
    newArray.push(yourArray[yl-1]);
    return newArray;
  }
}
var zeroNineteen = arrayEvery(range(0, 19), 4, 5);
var zeroSeventeen = arrayEvery(range(0, 17), 4, 5);
var fourThirtyTwo = arrayEvery(range(4, 32), 7, 3);
var threeFiftyThree = arrayEvery(range(3, 53), 8, 7);
console.log(zeroNineteen); console.log(zeroSeventeen);
console.log(fourThirtyTwo); console.log(threeFiftyThree);
```

Comment: If you can't figure out how to make this work for an arbitrary length, then you deserve to have it closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `n` index values, you should divide the length by (n - 1) and take `a[0]`, `a[res]`, `a[2*res]`, ..., `a[(n - 1)*res]` and `a[length - 1]` where `res` is `floor(length / (n - 1))` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mqBd/1/)):

```
function foo(rangeLow,rangeHigh,wanted) {
    var increment=Math.floor((rangeHigh-rangeLow)/(wanted - 1));
    var r = [rangeLow];
    for (var i = 1; i < wanted - 1; ++i){
        r.push(i * increment + rangeLow);
    }
    r.push(rangeHigh)
    console.log('r', r);
    return r;
}

foo(0, 19, 5) // result: 0 4 8 12 19
```

If you want a more evenly distributed result you can apply `Math.round` before pushing the value unto the array instead of flooring the increment beforehand (results in `[0,5,10,14,19]`, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mqBd/2/))

Comment: do Math.floor only before pushing `r.push(i * increment + rangeLow)` instead is better